# How can I replicate same functionality as insertPages() (insertPages function is from ionic 3) in ionic 6 with angular 13

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-routing, angular13, ionic6

I am migrating the Ionic 3 application to Ionic 6. In Ionic 3, there is one function, insertPages(), which will insert an array of pages at a given index in the navigation stack.But now I am using Ionic 6, and for that I am using Angular 13 routing.I am unable to replicate some functionality, such as insertPage().

I tried history.pushState() but not working